# Custom post url?

Tags: wordpress

I have made a new custom post like the following :

```
register_post_type( 'news',
            array( 
            'label' => __('News'), 
            'public' => true, 
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'rewrite' => false,
            'supports' => array(
                    'title',
                    'thumbnail',
                    'editor',
                    'excerpt')
                ) 
            );
```

But when i try to get to post url it look like the following 
`http://domainname.com/?news=post_title`

I want the url to be like 
`http://domainname.com/category/title`

so i tried the following post by changing the rewrite to `array('slug' =>'title', 'with_front' => true)`
but when i do that it give me 404 page not found

what is the problem here ?

Comment: how is your permalink structure setup under settings

Comment: /%category%/%postname%/

Comment: have you tried to switch to default and then switch back to /%category%/%postname%/

Comment: yes tried that .. but the same result .. could it something with the rewrite

Comment: let me test it out really quick for you

Answer (score 0):

Yes i knew what was the problem 
you have first to reset the permalink to default then create a new post type with `rewrite`
then make it back to `/%category%/%postname%/`